# Run ArcGIS IDW tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, inverse-distance-weighted

I am attempting to duplicate/implement an ArcGIS workflow with QGIS as part of a larger project. I have figured out most of them so far, but what stumps me is the Inverse Distance Weighting. The left is my result using QGIS IDW Interpolation, the right is the result I should be getting. Is there a parameter I need to set differently? How can I get the right result?

[image: result_comparison]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an unfortunate month and too many different issues in the workflow sorted out, finally the answer: It was the wrong tool. I was using IDW Interpolation (QGIS native algorithm), but even though the name matched, the method did not. I finally obtained the correct result when I used GRASS' **v.surf.idw**, which implements **Inverse Distance *Squared* Weighting**. That's the secret, it seems. ArcGIS (or at least the usage of it in our workflow?) actually uses that, IDSW, not IDW.

---

P.S.: I'm still not particularly familiar with ArcGIS. *Is* this IDSW a general thing there or not, does anyone know?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-idw-works.htm